# Make a Drop Down of QuickPart Keywords

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to make a drop down list of all the custom keywords using Quickpart keywords. So that they will be auto detected from the Sharepoint. Is there any work around this? [image]

Comment: What have you tried? Is this a programming question? If yes, please post your code and explain where you're having difficulty. If not, the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Just a note on Word jargon if you are doing web searches. What you are looking for is the Built-in Document Property Keywords which can be accessed through the Document Property Content Control under Quick Parts. It is important that you include SharePoint in any such search.